# Flask custom template filter

Tags: flask, jinja2

If I add custom template filter, even without injecting it into html. Any changes in template won't cause any effect after page reloading. Like if they are cached forever.

```
import re
@app.template_filter('test')
def format_number(value):
   return re.sub(r'\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))', ' ', value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like flask bug.

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

solves this problem